error: Overlapping copy - anchor
I am trying to create an array 1225 elements long. The program seems to have a problem with that, if I choose smaller number like 50 it works. Any suggestions?
pub type ProgramResult = Result<()>;
    
    #[program]
    pub mod my_crud {
        use super::*;
        pub fn create(ctx: Context<Create>) -> ProgramResult {
            let base_account = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;
            base_account.bump = ctx.bumps.base_account;
            base_account.colors = [0; 1225];
            Ok(())
        }
        pub fn set_color(ctx: Context<Colors>, data: [u32;2])-> ProgramResult{
            let base_account = &mut ctx.accounts.base_account;
            base_account.colors[data[0] as usize] = data[1];
            Ok(())
    
        }
    }
    #[derive(Accounts)]
    pub struct Create<'info> {
        #[account(init, 
            seeds = [b"counterpassword"],
            bump,
            payer = user, space = 16 + 4901)]
        pub base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>,
        #[account(mut)]
        pub user: Signer<'info>,
        pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    }
    #[derive(Accounts)]
    pub struct Colors<'info>{
        #[account(mut,
            seeds = [b"counterpassword"],
            bump = base_account.bump
            )]
        pub base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>
    }
    #[account]
    pub struct BaseAccount {
        pub bump: u8,
        pub colors : [u32; 1225]
    }


The error means that you are trying to write somewhere were you are not allowed to. So looks like you account size is too small.
To save an array of 1225 u32 (which has 8 byte) you would need 9800 bytes plus the bump of 1byte plus 8 byte for the anchor descriminator so 9809 bytes shoud fit your account.
Try increase the space here:
        #[account(init, 
            seeds = [b"counterpassword"],
            bump,
            payer = user, space = 16 + 4901)]
        pub base_account: Account<'info, BaseAccount>,

The maximum you can allocate via a CPI using the anchor init macro is 10000.
So it could barely fit. If you need more space you need to call realloc and increase the account size. You can find an example for that here:
https://github.com/solana-developers/anchor-zero-copy-example
